# Use two font in one expression in rdlc report

Tags: c#, fonts, expression, report, rdlc

I have a report that it has one expression.In this expression I want to use two different font. For example I want to write "Hello. My name is **Tavousi.**". That Tavousi is in other font.
Note that I want to use ONE expression.
How to I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with Report Viewer 2010, AFAIK a TextBox with one expression, can only have one text format.

An alternative is to use a Table from the Toolbox.
each cell in the table can have its own expression, and also its own text formatting.

Tip: if a row is empty, then set the Visibility condition for the whole row, to make sure that it does not take up whitespace.